# Good high school geometry textbook for self study

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I am entering my sophomore year of high school, because of how often I changed schools I never took geometry, this summer I took Pre Calc and am taking calc BC in sophomore year. This means I will have never taken a dedicated geometry class, I want to go through a textbook so that I can be prepared for things like the SAT/ACT and future math classes I will be taking that might expect students to have taken geometry. Any recommendations for textbooks, preferably nothing too expensive

Comment: Art of Problem Solving has a good Geometry textbook, but it's probably a lot harder than what you would need for SAT/ACT. (Certainly many of the problems in this book are much, much more challenging than the simple problems you would find in a standard curriculum.)

Comment: Thanks, It's not like im getting graded when I mess a problem up so I'm fine with the difficulty, I'll look into it.

Comment: The text [Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Ray-C-Jurgensen/dp/0395977274/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1534754684&sr=8-2&keywords=Geometry) by Jurgensen, Brown, and Jurgensen is useful.  You can save money by renting it.